# Sharing session or application data between users - best practise

Tags: asp.net, session

In my ASP.NET web application, I want to store an array of data that is accessible to all users of the site but retains a single state, modifiable by whichever user is logged in. What is the best approach for this? I understand I could probably go the route of using an Application wide variable, but are there better alternatives? I have also considered simply storing the state on the database and retrieving for each request.

Thanks in advance
Ian

Comment: I would use an xml file for such quest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go is via System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache if the state does not have to be persistent.

The cache is also availeble in the context of the page.

Comment: Won't that cache contents be specific to a specific user's session though?

Comment: Cache is Application Wide and Session is User specific.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you tell me if the following property would do the trick:

Comment: public Robot[] RobotInstances
        {
            get
            {
                return (Robot[])System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["RoboticInstances"];
            }
            set
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["RoboticInstances"] = value;
            }
        }

Comment: Yes that looks good to me but I would suggest using List<Robot> because you can add and remove instances from the list without the need of overwriting the full collection.

Comment: can you check the answer as accepted if this does what you want?

Answer (score 1):

My experience is use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache` and cache file. If the OS is lack of memory,the IIS will clear all Cache. If you want to keep the state for all user,you should keep copy of state in file(serial the object in file).

For example:I want to keep queue list in Cache for many users to get it.If the IIS reset the Cache object,it can read it in cache file.

```
            Stack<string> list = null;
            List<string> returnlist = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["PushQueueList"] != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        list = (Stack<string>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["PushQueueList"];
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        list = null;
                        //Log.LogToFile("PushQueueListError1:" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                if (list == null)//memory cache is null ,then read cache file
                {

                    try
                    {
                        list = (Stack<string>)Serialize.DeSerializeObj("pushqueue");//Deserialize object from file
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        list = null;
                        //Log.LogToFile("PushQueueListError2:" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
                {
                    if (list!=null && list.Count == 0)
                    {
                        return new List<string>();
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("PushQueueList");
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }
                    //Log.LogToFile("PushQueueList is empty,reload it");
                    DataSet ds = DB.GetSendQueueUserIDList(); ;
                    if (ds != null)
                    {
                        list = new Stack<string>();
                        DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dv.Count; i++)
                        {
                            list.Push(dv[i].Row["UserID"].ToString());
                        }
                        dv.Dispose();
                        ds.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log.LogToFile("PushQueueListError:" + ex.Message);
            }

            if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ReturnCount; i++)
                {
                    if (list.Count > 0)
                    {
                        returnlist.Add(list.Pop());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.LogToFile("PushQueueList OK");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("PushQueueList", list, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                                                             TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default,
                                                             null);
                Serialize.SerializeObj(list, "pushqueue");
            }
            return returnlist;
        }
```

The serial method is below:

```
    public static bool SerializeObj(object obj, string FileName)
    {
        string LogFileDir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFile"];
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(LogFileDir))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(LogFileDir);
        }
        string FilePath = LogFileDir + FileName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".bin";
        try
        {
            IFormatter _formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using(Stream _stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                _formatter.Serialize(_stream, obj);
                _stream.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static object DeSerializeObj(string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            string LogFileDir = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFile"];
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(LogFileDir))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(LogFileDir);
            }
            object objStd = null;
            string FilePath = LogFileDir + FileName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".bin";

            using(Stream _stream = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter _b = new BinaryFormatter();
                objStd = _b.Deserialize(_stream);
                _stream.Close();
            }
            return objStd;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```